# my javascript code not work in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript

hey i have javascript code for slider, my code work 100% in internet explorer but it's not working in chrome or firefox.

this my html code -->

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/JS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="slidermo0();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="stmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                    <li><img src="images/search.png"/><input type="text" /></li>
                    <li><a href="#">مرحبا</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <img id="mainimg" src="sss.jpg" />
            <img id="logo" src="sss.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">رئيس المجلس</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul>
                <li id="s1" onmouseover="slidermo1();" onmouseout="slidermou1();"><h1 id="s1txt">تأجيل محاكمة مرسي لجلسة 1 فبراير لتعذر نقله إلى مقر  </h1></li>
                <li id="s2" onmouseover="slidermo2();" onmouseout="slidermou2();"><h1 id="s2txt">تأجيل محاكمة مرسي لجلسة 1 فبراير لتعذر نقله  </h1></li>
                <li id="s3" onmouseover="slidermo3();" onmouseout="slidermou3();"><h1 id="s3txt"> محاكمة مرسي لجلسة 1 فبراير لتعذر نقله إلى مقر المحاكمة </h1></li>
                <li id="s4" onmouseover="slidermo4();" onmouseout="slidermou4();"><h1 id="s4txt">تأجيل  لجلسة 1 فبراير لتعذر نقله إلى مقر المحاكمة </h1></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mimg">
                <img id="sim4" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000851647346/134bd91486fb1f3dcaf9a94929d08580.jpeg" />
                <img id="sim3" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3477392906/f1907df0bd76668deac4a5e31a22fbe7.jpeg" />
                <img id="sim2" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000777707394/262a47f6acb49b39a454e7f552ad5854.jpeg" />
                <img id="sim1" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000700068115/a218e2c8dde5b511417034dd5c04f01b.jpeg" />
            </div>

            <div class="binfo">
                <h1 id="smtxt"></h1>
                <p>كان اللواء أمين عز الدين، مساعد أول وزير الداخلية مدير أمن الإسكندرية، قد قال إنه «تعذر نقل الرئيس المعزول محمد مرسي إلى مقر محاكمته بأكاديمية ... </p>
            </div>
            <img id="arrow" src="images/arrow.png" />
        </div>
            <div class="lnews">
                <div class="title">
                    <span>اخر الاخبار</span>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this my javascript code ===>

```
var timer = null;
var myimg = "sim1";
var top = "sim2";

function imgslide() {
    if (top != myimg) {
        document.getElementById("sim1").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim2").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim3").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim4").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim1").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim2").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim3").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById("sim4").style.zIndex = "0";
        document.getElementById(top).style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById(top).style.zIndex = "1";
        document.getElementById(myimg).style.zIndex = "2";
        document.getElementById(myimg).style.opacity = "0";
        $("#" + myimg).animate({ opacity: "1" }, "slow");
    }
}
function slidermo0() {
    myimg = "sim1";
    imgslide();
    top = "sim1";
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.top = "0px";
    $("#s1").addClass("liover");
    $("#s2").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s3").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s4").removeClass("liover");
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s1txt").innerText;
    timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo2(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo3(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo4(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo0() }, 3000); }, 3000); }, 3000); }, 3000);
}

function slidermo1() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    myimg = "sim1";
    imgslide();
    top = "sim1";
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s1txt").innerText;
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.top = "0px";
    $("#s1").addClass("liover");
    $("#s2").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s3").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s4").removeClass("liover");
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s1txt").innerText;
}

function slidermo2() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    myimg = "sim2";
    imgslide();
    top = "sim2";
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s2txt").innerText;
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.top = "81px";
    $("#s2").addClass("liover");
    $("#s1").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s3").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s4").removeClass("liover");
}

function slidermo3() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    myimg = "sim3";
    imgslide();
    top = "sim3";
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s3txt").innerText;
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.top = "163px";
    $("#s3").addClass("liover");
    $("#s1").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s2").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s4").removeClass("liover");
}

function slidermo4() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    myimg = "sim4";
    imgslide();
    top = "sim4";
    document.getElementById("smtxt").innerText = document.getElementById("s4txt").innerText;
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.top = "245px";
    $("#s4").addClass("liover");
    $("#s1").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s2").removeClass("liover");
    $("#s3").removeClass("liover");
}

function slidermou1() {
    slidermo0();
    myimg = "sim2";
}

function slidermou2() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo3(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo4(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo0() }, 3000); }, 3000); }, 3000);
    myimg = "sim3";
}

function slidermou3() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo4(); timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo0(); }, 3000); }, 3000);
    myimg = "sim4";
}

function slidermou4() {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { slidermo0(); }, 3000);
    myimg = "sim1";
}
```

and this my code demo, just look at slider -->
http://schools.org.il/Default2.aspx

i have search for solution for my problem 2 days but i didn't find it, can any one help?!

Comment: that code hurts my eyes :/

Comment: Side note: to make code even more confusing/strange consider using `document.write` too :)... Why you are using such random mix of JQuery and raw JavaScript in place of CSS?

Answer (score 2):

`top` is a <s>reserved keyword</s> variable that cannot be overridden. You cannot use it.

```
document.getElementById(top)
```

This is the same as

```
document.getElementById(window.top)
```

which is not

```
document.getElementById("sim2")  //nope
```

as you expected.

[image]

Comment: it is not a reserved _keyword_, but a protected _property_ of `window` and because `var top` appears in the global scope `var` has no effect and because of this `top` refers still to the `window.top` so it is not writeable.

Comment: so what i should to do?!

Comment: @user3080555 - You can just change the variable name and you are done. PS: It seems that you have jQuery included but you are not using and `document.getElementById` are all over the place. Also [you shouldn't copy your `slidermou#` functions by hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @user3080555 - You can mark my answer as helpful if it helped you.